# Is a C program called by PHP safe and fast?

Tags: php, c, apache, web

If I create C programs for retrieving data and saving data to a database as well as to do more complex computation, is it safe and efficient to use these programs in PHP as an exec() command?

I'm trying to learn C and it would be great to add interactivity to my programs through a web interface using PHP and Apache. I'm not planning on having lots of users nor is security a huge risk.

Assuming i'm careful to clean all user inputed data. What are the possible complications? What might be some alternatives.

It seems safer and less complex than hosting a web server entirely in C.

Comment: Maybe. It depends. And it has nothing specifically to do with either C or PHP.

Comment: As The Knuth famously said, *‘Premature optimisation is the root of all evil’*. This sounds like a lot of premature optimisation to me...

Answer (score 2):

I also used this technique for some applications. Using C will be no less **safe** than PHP, as the permissions will be the same for the compiled program as for the PHP script which started it with `exec()`.

Be careful not to **overoptimize**: programming in C takes a lot more time than in PHP to achieve the same task. Using C would only help you in parts of the application that would be very computationally intensive and faster, such as:

- **calculations** on many, many numbers
- manipulating very **big amounts of data** in memory

If you don't find yourself in one of these cases, the execution time would probably no be much affected... but the programming time would, especially if you are new to C! Here is a thing for which C is not better at than PHP:

- **database** interfacing

Also, you might consider using **C++ instead of C**. The difference in execution time is barely noticeable, but you would benefit from:

- **object** oriented programming
- "easy" **strings** manipulation
- STL **containers**